java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem
Im having trouble with a java.swing application im using eclipes here is the full codebase:
<
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class IsometricViewport extends JPanel {
    private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
    private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 32;

    public IsometricViewport() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 640));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Draw isometric tiles
        for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += TILE_WIDTH) {
            for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += TILE_HEIGHT) {
                drawIsometricTile(g, x, y);
            }
        }

        // TODO: Draw characters and other game elements
    }

    private void drawIsometricTile(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        int isoX = (x - y) / 2;
        int isoY = (x + y) / 2;

        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(isoX, isoY, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(isoX, isoY, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Isometric Viewport");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new IsometricViewport());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

this is the only thing from the debug console
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
at main.IsometricViewport.main(viewport.java:39)
im using java.swing for the first time and this is like my 5th week of java so I don't know much

Is that really the only message the compiler gave? Please read How to Ask. You should provide complete error message

Copied everything except the package statement and the code compiles and executes fine for me.

Based on camickr's statement, stop looking at the code. The problem is somewhere else.

You have run into Eclipse's "helpful" feature that allows you to run code with compilation / build errors.  Turn it off!!  Then go back and correct >>all<< of the errors, before you attempt to run the code.  If you don't understand the compilation errors that Eclipse is complaining about ... add them to the question (as text) so that we can advise on what to do.

I got the code working The file was named wrong

If this is your 5th week using java I would advise not using Lambdas and type out every line of code because you want to have a strong understand of the basics. Your main method is a good example of a lambda is.
